# Low Search - Upgrade from 2.3.1 to 3.0.1 caused a field search to stop functioning properly

Tags: low-search

I recently upgraded from Low Search 2.3.1 to 3.0.1.

I have these 2 selects in my `{exp:low_search:form}` to search for a range of `birthdate`, a field with a fieldtype of EE's native `Date`

```
<select name="range-to:birthdate">
    <option value="1995-11-29">18</option>
    <option value="1994-11-29">19</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1993-11-29">20</option>
    ....
    <option value="1963-11-29">50</option>
</select>

<select name="range-from:birthdate">
    <option value="1994-11-30">18</option>
    <option value="1993-11-30">19</option>
    <option value="1992-11-30">20</option>
    ....
    <option selected="selected" value="1987-11-30">25</option>
    ....
    <option value="1800-01-01">51+</option>
</select>
```

When I tested the filter in the old version, this was filtering results properly. But now it doesn't seem to filter since I still get all results no matter the option I choose in the selects.

Is there something that I need to do in the Low Search Update to make this work? I have completely rebuilt the indexes after update.

**MORE INFO**:

I asked this [question](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low_search_date_range_problems) before. It solved the problem for me. Nothing has been changed in the implementation.

In my `low_search_pre_search` hook handler function, the code convert the dates to be of format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM AM/PM`.

A quick test indicated that it was outputting values in the correct format, `1993-11-29 11:59 PM`, `1987-11-30 12:00 AM`

So safe to say that this is not the cause of the problem?

Comment: Picked up the ticket on GetSat: https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low_search_upgrade_from_2_3_1_to_3_0_1_caused_a_field_search_to_stop_functioning_properly